# ValueError: too many values to unpack PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am a beginner, here is my code.

```
from PIL import Image

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/name/Desktop/Project/Image/'
img = ["lighthouse.jpg", "mountain.jpg", "image.jpg"]
pil_img = [Image.open(UPLOAD_FOLDER + x) for x in img]
ratio, height = [y.size for y in pil_img]
```

I've seen a few questions similar to this, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix this code. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: You are basically trying to unpack an iterable of size 3 into 2 variables on the left side. Make sure you understand what you are doing (size != shape) and debug the sizes / shapes of those components. And try to react to the first commen!

Answer (score 0):

```
ratio, height = [y.size for y in pil_img]
```

In the above code you are expecting to receive two values but if you could see it you are just returning `y.size` so according to your code the below line might work

```
height = [y.size for y in pil_img]
```